# Flutter How To Ensure a Function is Called Whenever App Hot Reloads in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, devops

I have a Flutter App that relies on a correct Server URL being set based on the environment it is running in. However, my function seems to not be called during Hot reloads.

I have at the top of my `main.dart`:

```
String TARGET_URL; /// TODO: Replace once figure out how to set environment Variables based on type of device.

void setTargetURLForEnv() async {
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo = DeviceInfoPlugin();
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo = await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
    if (iosDeviceInfo.isPhysicalDevice) {
      TARGET_URL = 'http://aws-server-url.com';
    } else {
      TARGET_URL = 'http://localhost:6900';
    }
  }
}

void main() async {
  runApp(App());
  setTargetURLForEnv();
}
```

Hot Reloads cause `TARGET_URL` to be null, even when running on a iOS simulator. How do I force this method to be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setTargetURLForEnv() above the runApp(App()). I think because it is outside the App(), hot reloading the app won't execute the function. Try hot restart ('R') instead of hot reload in terminal.

Comment: Moving `setTargetURLForEnv()` did not work. What exactly do you mean by 'Try hot restart ('R') '?  Currently Android Studio does the Hot reload for me when saving changes

Comment: Hot reload just reloads the current widget and its children widgets according to my knowledge (I am also a beginner).You have written the called function outside the parent widget. So you have to restart the app. In VS code hot restart button is 'R'. I don't know about Android Studio. Try googling Hot restart button in Android studio

Comment: I see. So Hot restarts on save is NOT a thing.

Comment: During save it is hot reload. It sure speeds up development but sometimes you need hot restart. Glad I was of help.